# Loop optimizations in JavaScript, do I need it?

Tags: javascript

I know that JavaScript is an *interpreted* language, which doesn't have the benefits of code optimization that may be done for a *compiled* language.

So I was curious, which would be better to use?

A. With .length in the loop:

```
//Assuming 'arr' in an array of an arbitrary length
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    //Do work on element arr[i];
}
```

B. or this:

```
//Assuming 'arr' in an array of an arbitrary length
var arrLen = arr.length;
for(var i = 0; i < arrLen; i++)
{
    //Do work on element arr[i];
}
```

Comment: It depends on the JS interpreter and how often the code is run.  In general, caching the length speeds things up, but if the code is run a lot, many implementations have a just-in-time compiler that will compile it so it is effectively cached by the interpreter instead of your code.

Comment: Try it and tell us the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute

Comment: Not much difference: http://jsperf.com/fastest-array-loops-in-javascript/56

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460123/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-to-assigning-the-end-point-of-a-for-loop/25460215#25460215